# What would be english equivalent of Hindi proverb char aane ki murgi barah aane ka masala-Chicken is dirt cheap but its ingredients are costing a bomb

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, idioms, proverbs

What would be english equivalent of Hindi proverb "char aane (Rs. 0.25) ki murgi (Chicken) barah aane (Rs. 0.75) ka masala (spice)" is an old phrase around 60's and the 70's India which mean Chicken is dirt cheap (say 10$) but its minuscule spice ingredients costing a bomb (say 300$)

Example 1: Wow, two thousand dollar wheel rims on a three hundred dollar car.
Example 2: 208 hrs worth paperwork and teamwork on a 1/2 hrs project. (Office setting).
Example 3: 1 hours of interview and you 2 1/2 months of preparation.
Example 4: 1 hours of exhibition for the VIPs and three month of refurbishment and $ 90,000 spent for what.

Comment: Maybe *lipstick on a pig*.  But the monetary aspect makes me think of *stepping over dollars to pick up pennies* or *throwing good money after bad*